# Hadoop 2.6 multinode cluster failed on connection exception when running example jar

Tags: hadoop, connection-refused

Any example hadoop 2.6 mapreduce application is giving same error- java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; The error output is:

```
    hduser@localhost:~$ hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /usr/local/hadoop/input  output_wordcount
15/05/26 06:01:14 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.111.72:8040
15/05/26 06:01:15 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/05/26 06:01:15 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/05/26 06:01:15 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1432599812585_0002
15/05/26 06:01:16 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1432599812585_0002
15/05/26 06:01:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost.localdomain:8088/proxy/application_1432599812585_0002/
15/05/26 06:01:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1432599812585_0002
15/05/26 06:01:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1432599812585_0002 running in uber mode : false
15/05/26 06:01:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/26 06:01:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1432599812585_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1432599812585_0002 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1432599812585_0002_000002. Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1 to localhost.localdomain:56148 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.launch(AMLauncher.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.run(AMLauncher.java:254)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 9 more
. Failing the application.
15/05/26 06:01:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

My /etc/hosts looks like this-

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996

192.168.111.72  master
192.168.111.65  slave1
192.168.111.66  slave2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have commented ipv6 lines out after trying many other possibilities. I am wondering where the error actually is. Thanks in advance for reply.

Thanks for your reply @Ashok. But jps on master and slaves show all demons are runnning. Attaching output-

Master
    hduser@localhost:~$ jps
    23518 Jps
    10442 NameNode
    10752 SecondaryNameNode
    12348 ResourceManager

Slave1
    hduser@localhost:~$ jps
    28691 NodeManager
    13987 Jps
    27298 DataNode

And same for slave2.

Comment: I have two slaves running; slave1, slave2. But 
 yarn node -list is showing both localhost
15/05/27 06:32:50 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.111.72:8040
Total Nodes:2
         Node-Id      Node-State Node-Http-Address Number-of-Running-Containers
localhost.localdomain:58139         RUNNING localhost.localdomain:8042                            0
localhost.localdomain:57312         RUNNING localhost.localdomain:8042                            0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution!!

```
Call From localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1 to localhost.localdomain:56148 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

Both master and slaves were having host names of localhost.localdomain in /etc/hostname.
I changed host names  of slaves to slave1 and slave2. That worked.
Thank you everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Namenode not running, or any of the other daemons are not running, also make sure you can ping between the nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But jps on master and slaves show all demons are runnning. Attaching output-
hduser@localhost:~$ jps
23518 Jps
10442 NameNode
10752 SecondaryNameNode
12348 ResourceManager